# Paste incremental values in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

How can I run a loop in VBA so that the sequence looks like in green an pink color?

Because when I use this code is actually just paste all number 1. not increase.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("E2:E" & iLast).FillDown
```

[image]

Comment: Will the pattern consistently be 1, 2, 3 for the whole column? You could just use `=MOD(ROW(),3)+1`.

Comment: could you please be more precise what you want to do?

Comment: Thank You so muchh :) -jsheeran.. i got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to solve it.

i use this formula

```
=MOD(ROW()-2,3)+1.
```

Thank's you all..appreciate your help. <3

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cleanest way, but it will do the trick.

```
Sub InsertSequenceAndColours()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim iLast As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iSeq As Integer
    Dim iColRGB(2, 3) As Integer
    Dim iIncremColour As Integer 'used to determine the colour to use
    Dim iColour As Integer

    'set RGB Colours; change as needed
    'colour 0 (green)
    iColRGB(0, 1) = 146
    iColRGB(0, 2) = 208
    iColRGB(0, 3) = 80
    'colour 1 (pink)
    iColRGB(1, 1) = 255
    iColRGB(1, 2) = 225
    iColRGB(1, 3) = 236

    'change to 0 if you want to start with colour 1 (pink)
    iIncremColour = 1


    'declare worksheet to work on
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name)

    With ws
        'find last row
        iLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        'loop through column C
        For i = 2 To iLast
            iSeq = iSeq + 1
            If .Cells(i, 3).Value <> .Cells(i - 1, 3).Value Then
                iSeq = 1
                iIncremColour = iIncremColour + 1
            End If

            'assign Seq. No. to cell (column E)
            .Cells(i, 5).Value = iSeq

            'find if iIncremColor is odd or even. output: 0 or 1
            iColour = iIncremColour Mod 2

            'assign colour to col C D E
            .Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, 5)).Interior.Color = _
                    RGB(iColRGB(iColour, 1), iColRGB(iColour, 2), iColRGB(iColour, 3))
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

It finds out the Seq "1" (Col E) by finding the first occurrence of "No" (Col C); Seq "2, 3" are just incremental (so it will work also with more than 3 occurrences).
Same with colour. For each "Seq 1" it increments a number; by checking if this number is odd or even it assign one colour or the other.

Please Note I use worksheet codename to work (if you're not familiar with it, please google it), which I strongly advise since it will work even if you decide to change the name of your worksheet in excel.
When VBA requests to work with worksheet name or index, you can trick it by using `codename.Name` or `codename.Index`.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach via array**

You can fill an array and write it back to your target range:

```
Sub FlexibleRange()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")    ' << change to your     sheet name
Dim start As Long, last As Long, i As Long                       ' declare variables
start = 2: last = 100                                            ' <~~ change to your individual rows
Dim v: ReDim v(start To last, 1 To 1)                            ' variant datafield array, counter

For i = start To last
    v(i, 1) = (i - start) Mod 3 + 1                              ' assign values
Next i 

ws.Range("E" & start & ":E" & last) = v                          ' write numbers to column E
End Sub
```